# Is there a complete list of registered commands anywhere?

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

I just installed a helpful statusbar commands extensions and it gets you to make a list of commands you want to have buttons for.

But when I got around to adding the command for fold all, I couldn't figure out what its parent was,

turns out it's `editor`

is there a list of all available commands with their hierarchies?

Answer (score 0):

I see it is in Keyboard Shortcuts

That's fine, a little unintuitive but oh well!

ty ty